# EACCES error using Yeoman to install angular

Tags: node.js, angularjs, yeoman

I tried running

```
yo angular --coffee --minsafe
```

but I get this error

```
   Error: EACCES, permission denied '/Users/Basil/.config/configstore/insight-yo.yml'
        at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
        at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:966:15)
        at Object.create.all.set (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/configstore.js:39:7)
        at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/configstore.js:30:11)
        at new Insight (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/lib/insight.js:20:16)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/bin/yo:26:15)
        at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

I have checked the issues on Github and seen [npm / yeoman install generator-angular without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212175/npm-yo-keeps-asking-for-sudo-permission) but can't seem to get it to work

node v0.10.17
npm v1.2.10

```
find / -name 'yeoman'
```

/Users/Basil/.node/node_modules/.bin/yeoman
/Users/Basil/.node/node_modules/yeoman
/Users/Basil/.node/node_modules/yeoman/bin/yeoman
/Users/Basil/.node/node_modules/yeoman/node_modules/yeoman-generators/lib/generators/yeoman
/Users/Basil/.npm/yeoman
/Users/Basil/.npm/yeoman/0.9.6/package/bin/yeoman
/Users/Basil/.npm/yeoman-generators/0.9.5/package/lib/generators/yeoman

Comment: OS? What method did you use to install Node?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue with this:

```
Sudo chown Basil /Users/Basil/.config/configstore/update-notifier-yo.yml
```

If you run into this issue, try this out, replacing "Basil" with your username

Comment: FYI - had to remove the file name to get it to work - meaning, gave my user access to the folder /configstore/ not necessarily to the file itself.

Answer (score 7):

You can just use **npm cache clean** and  **bower cache clean**.

Comment: `npm cache clean` was sufficient for me

Answer (score 1):

`Sudo chown Basil /Users/Basil/.config/configstore/update-notifier-yo.yml` (Remove trailing chown) Replace Basil with your username.

`Sudo chown <yourusername> /Users/<yourusername>/.config/configstore/update-notifier-yo.yml` Keepinging in mind your username does not include the dollar sign.

This corrected the Error when running Yeoman:

```
EACCES, permission denied '/Users/<yourusername>/.config/configstore/update-notifier-yo.yml'
```

Answer (score 1):

If the above doesn't work simply delete all files in the /Users/USER_NAME/.config/configstore/ directory and run yo angular again. Replace USER_NAME with your user name.

Comment: Not sure why that worked, but it did. I chown'd the to user and root in my case, and still no dice. But for some reason when I deleted the files and re-ran my yo command it worked great. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it in Windows.
I have done three things, which one have fixed it I am not sure.

1. Run cmd prompt as administrator.
2. takeown /? this command is equivalent to chown (linux) but for windows.
3. cacls -cacls  /E /T /G :F
4. simply go in $USER /Users/calvin/.config/configstore/ and make files unhidden.

it worked for me like charm.
I have been trying to fix this since many days.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too late to answer but in order to help others, changing both permissions (chmod) and owner (chown) is what worked for me on Ubuntu:

```
sudo chmod g+rwx /home/myusername/.config/configstore
sudo chown myusername /home/myusername/.config/configstore
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me :

```
//Update npm to the latest version. Works for to upgrade 1.x to 2.x.
$ npm install -g npm stable    
// Assign group permissions to the parent directory.
$ chmod g+rwx /root /root/.config /root/.config/configstore
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply remove the .config folder from user home directory
`rm -rf /home/user/.config` then run `sudo yo` which will create .config again and reset previous faulty configuration. Mine is working fine after apply this approach.