# Why can't i npm install nodemon or supervisor on OSX 10.8.4?

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, nodemon, node-supervisor

I'm just trying to install nodemon or supervisor using terminal, and I keep getting this error which I don't understand.  I tried running as the administrator with `sudo npm install supervisor -g` which seemed to work, but than didn't when i deleted/added some js code.  Any ideas?

```
Squirrels-MacBook-Air:lesson7_examples Squirrel$ npm install nodemon -g
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nodemon
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nodemon
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.4.1
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "nodemon" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Squirrel/Documents/Code/Memry/Memry_Mongoose
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.21
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.11
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon
npm ERR! fstream_type Directory
npm ERR! fstream_class DirWriter
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon'
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Squirrel/Documents/Code/Memry/Memry_Mongoose/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
Squirrels-MacBook-Air:lesson7_examples Squirrel$
```

P.S. I'm running this on a pre-existing template and my dependencies are

```
  "dependencies": {
    "mongoose": "~3.6.15",
    "express": "~3.3.4",
    "jade": "~0.34.1",
    "email-validator": "~0.1.2"
  }
```

When I tried sudo this is what happened:

```
sudo npm install supervisor -g --save 
Password:
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/supervisor
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/supervisor
/usr/local/bin/node-supervisor -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/supervisor/lib/cli-wrapper.js
/usr/local/bin/supervisor -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/supervisor/lib/cli-wrapper.js
supervisor@0.5.6 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/supervisor
```

Which seemed to work.  But than in the application code I began to add and delete javascript and click save, yet the effects wouldn't take place unless I restarted the server within terminal.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Did it work using `sudo`? What exactly did you do when you said "*seemed to work, but than didn't when i deleted/added some js code*"?

Comment: There I added what happened when I used sudo above.

Comment: Indeed, using sudo looks like it worked. The fact that your server behavior isn't updated when you save your file is probably related to a bad usage of nodemon. I'd suggest opening another question, as your nodemon install looks fine.

Comment: I deleted a chunk of code in my application which had no effect when I refreshed the browser, but only when I restarted the server in terminal.  Shouldn't that use nodemon or supervisor?  Thanks very much for ur help.

Comment: Do you run your application like [this](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#usage)? Do you watch the needed directory as stated [here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#monitoring-multiple-directories)?

Comment: Ok I see what I was doing wrong.  I was typing `node app.js` and not `nodemon app.js`.  Thanks a lot.  I feel pretty dumb.  That is how I'm suppose to do, right?   Thanks again.

Comment: Exactly! That's why `nodemon` has to be installed globally, so that you can use it as an executable anywhere, just as you'd use the `node`  command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're encountering an `EACCES` error, which means you don't have the rights to create a directory in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon` as a standard user in Mac OS X.

There are two solutions:

- Run the same command as a superuser, using `sudo`. The package will be installed in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`.
- Change npm's settings to install all of your global packages into one of your private folders, that your user has ownership of. See [this relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212175/npm-yo-keeps-asking-for-sudo-permission/18277225#18277225) that explains step-by-step the process.

Comment: I tried `sudo npm install supervisor -g --save` which seemed to pass, but than didn't work.  For instance deleting a chunk of code in my application had no effect when I refreshed the browser, but only when I restarted the server in terminal.

Answer (score 12):

Late to the party, but it is important to note that you should avoid using `sudo` when npm installing.  It is a huge security risk to `sudo npm install` as you are giving arbitrary scripts root access to your machine.

Instead you should make yourself the owner of the directories in which the NPM

`sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local`

and then

`sudo chown -R $USER ~/.npm`

Now you should be able to run the commands without sudo:

`npm install supervisor -g --save`

Comment: No. `/usr/local` should NOT belong to your user account. (Homebrew does it this way, but, well, they're wrong.)

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the question, but you should check out [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) (node's answer to [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/)).

**Install**:

`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.25.4/install.sh | bash`

Then add `. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` to your `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, or `~/.zshrc`

**Usage**:

If you wanted to use version 0.10, run `nvm install 0.12.7` (or `nvm install stable`), then `nvm use 0.12.7`.

Install your libs, EACCESS error-free, and go to town. `npm install -g supervisor` works just fine!

> To load a specific version default in new tabs, use the command `nvm alias default 0.12.7`

Comment: To make a version of node default using NVM the proper command is `nvm alias default 0.12.7`. All new tabs will open with default version running.