# npm install vs sudo npm install -g

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, sudo

for some packages I have to run `sudo npm install -g` while for others `npm install` will suffice.

Why and what's the difference?

For example:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli  # doesn't work
sudo npm install -g grunt-cli  # works
npm install websocket-stream # works
```

Is `sudo` necessary only with the `-g` flag?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`npm` installs packages locally, ie. in a `node_modules` folder inside your current folder. This allows your application to depend on specific packages versions, without having to mess up with a global list of installed packages on your system. See the first paragraph of [Isaac's blog post](http://blog.izs.me/post/1675072029/10-cool-things-you-probably-didnt-realize-npm-could-do) (*Handle multiple versions of the same thing at the same time*), which explains well how `npm` avoids the dependency hell often encountered in other programming ecosystems.

On the other hand, some packages are meant to be used as command line utilities, such as `grunt-cli`, `mocha` or `json`. In order to use them everywhere, you need to install them globally, hence the `-g` parameter.

Please note that you shouldn't need `sudo` to install global packages, see [this relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212175/npm-yo-keeps-asking-for-sudo-permission/18277225#18277225) for more information.

Comment: On Ubuntu, if there is no package.json file in the current directory, running npm install somemodule will install sommodule in ~/.npm and not in ./node_modules

Comment: @Paul Mougel alright, we should not install global packages with sudo, so it should not throw error then...

Answer (score 2):

Looks like permissions issue. -g install it globally (you will need to 'root'), but its not a good idea to install that as root
In terminal run:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
```

Answer (score 0):

`npm install -g grunt-cli` installs the package in the global mode, every user could use it.
Without `-g` you just install it in the current directory.
If you are not the root user, you need to use `sudo` for the `-g`. 
If you use `npm` without `-g` and you have write permission to the current directory, then 
`sudo` is not necessary. Otherwise, you still need it.

Answer (score 0):

`-g` is global, without just installs the package locally.

You run it with sudo as it installs to folders which your default user may not have access to by default.

Answer (score 0):

`grunt-cli` will provide an executable that will be put in your `PATH`, so depending on how you configured your system it will require root access.
See [this post from npm creator](http://howtonode.org/introduction-to-npm), particularly the part about using sudo with npm.

`websocket-stream` is a library, your code will use it so it will be easier to perform some tasks, usually it will be installed at the root of your project, in the `node_modules` folder.