# What does `echo prefix = ~/.node >> ~/.npmrc` mean?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm reading this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18277225/3290121) on running `yo` and `npm` without `sudo` by saving their results in `~/.node`.

It uses `echo prefix = ~/.node >> ~/.npmrc`, and I'd like to know what each symbol means and how they work together in this case.

Comment: Also, its oddd that they dont just use `npm config set prefix ~/.node` which would save it in the `~/.npmrc` file

Comment: see also: http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=echo+prefix+%3D+~%2F.node+%3E%3E+~%2F.npmrc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo prefix = ~/.node
```

This simply prints a string to standard output. The shell will expand `~` to the value of `$HOME`, so the string printed might be something like `"prefix = /home/randwa1k"` (without the quotation marks, of course).

```
... >> ~/.npmrc
```

This redirects the output of the `echo` command to the file `~/.npmrc`, which expands to the same thing as `$HOME/.npmrc`. Using `>>` rather than `>` means that the output is appended to the end of the file.

So the command as a whole appends one line of text to a file called `.npmrc` in your home directory.

The effects of that change to the `.npmrc` file are going to depend on whatever programs read that file.