# Unable to create yeoman webapp

Tags: node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I get this when I try to create a webapp with `yeoman`.

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/configstore.js:66
                throw err;
                      ^
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/root/.config/configstore/insight-yo.yml'
You don't have access to this file.

    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:436:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:975:15)
    at Object.create.all.set (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/configstore.js:56:8)
    at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/configstore.js:19:11)
    at new Insight (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/lib/insight.js:23:34)
    at process.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/lib/push.js:11:16)
    at process.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at handleMessage (child_process.js:322:10)
    at Pipe.channel.onread (child_process.js:349:11)
```

I googled and I tried the following things, but it didn't help:

```
chown root /root/.config/configstore/insight-yo.yml 

chown myusername /root/.config/configstore/insight-yo.yml
```

Installed `npm-sudo-fix` and ran it, and no luck yet.

I am on Debian Wheezy and have npm 1.4.4.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. I ran the command below, It fixed my problem:

```
mkdir -p /root/.config/configstore

chmod g+rwx /root /root/.config /root/.config/configstore
```

Comment: Thank you Mohammad Amir!

Comment: so now the access to /root is permitted to anyone?

Answer (score 3):

The same issue happened to me, i was in root mode user#. I just get back to normal user$ and it worked.  i am using Zorin OS

Comment: yeah, old to node, new to Mac (again). just restart the terminal... don't know what's up with not being able to run as root (just for the install of npm etc) and then running it but whatever

Comment: Worked for me. Hurray!!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by running:

```
echo prefix = ~/.node >> ~/.npmrc
```

and

```
export PATH=$HOME/.node/bin:$PATH
```

Explanation here:

[Error installing yeoman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330273/error-installing-yeoman)
[What does `echo prefix = ~/.node >> ~/.npmrc` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21948653/what-does-echo-prefix-node-npmrc-mean)
[npm / yeoman install generator-angular without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212175/npm-yeoman-install-generator-angular-without-sudo)

Comment: It didnt work. I am having issue: Error: Cannot find module './lib/env'

Comment: Sure, thanks for letting me know. I just posted what I did to get it running. Hopefully other answers might help.

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed it in Windows. I have done three things, which one have fixed it I am not sure.

Run cmd prompt as administrator.

`takeown /?` this command is equivalent to `chown` (linux) but for windows.

```
cacls -cacls /E /T /G :F
```

simply go in `$USER` `/Users/calvin/.config/configstore/` and make files unhidden.

it worked for me like charm. I have been trying to fix this since many days.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue building a meanjs app on Ubuntu and I've fixed this issue using `sudo` instead of `root`:

```
sudo npm install -g yo generator-meanjs bower grunt
```

Then i could build the app without being asked for password again:

```
yo meanjs
```

> sudo allows user to act as root without root login, it is more secure to use sudo instead of logging in as root.
>   [sudo vs root - askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592825/whats-the-difference-between-sudo-and-changing-to-root)

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that yo is not granted to use some of the nodejs modules. basically, y the problem is related to authorization of yo by node package manager "npm", to fix this run this command first

```
sudo npm install --global yo --allow-root
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the [`chmod` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34257285/33499) seemed to work at first, I got a similar error later, for a different folder. But [here](https://github.com/yeoman/yo/issues/348#issuecomment-220369719) I found this workaround which fixed that too:

```
sed -i -e '/rootCheck/d' "${NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX}/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js"
```

If `yo` is run as root, `rootCheck` will downgrade to UID 1000 (on Linux) or 501 (on OS X). This causes the permission error. But in a docker container, you might want to run as root, so you have no other option.

You need to rerun this command after upgrading yeoman. In case `NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX` is not defined, you can use:

```
export NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=$(npm config get prefix)
```