# npm installs express into /root/.node

Tags: node.js, npm

At the begging when express-generator couldn't installed I've used

> sudo su

To install it, but after reading the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212175/npm-yo-keeps-asking-for-sudo-permission/18277225#18277225) I've done what he said but it didn't helped and now the npm installs express and express-generator into /root/.node

> express@4.4.1 /root/.node/lib/node_modules/express

Does anybody knows how to solve it?

Comment: What do you want to happen? I'm not sure which you want - for express to be installed there or for it not to be. Please clarify

Comment: As far as I know it's not good that it's installed into /root so I want it to be installed like it should be

Comment: Why not just delete `/root/.node/` and reinstall **without** sudo or su?

Comment: @Avery because without sudo it's not installing

Comment: Define not installing

Comment: @Avery It says something similar to this - Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-express'.
I'm completely confused. Is it ok that npm installs modules into /root?

Comment: Check your `~/.npmrc` file to make sure your prefix was actually set.

Comment: @Avery It gives me "No such file or directory" when I insert the line you gave me

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it using the following solution that has been suggested here - 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20750211/878244