# Error Installing Yeoman on windows: "getaddrinfo eai_again registry.npmjs.org:80"

Tags: node.js, yeoman, npm-install

I am on a corporate network and I am trying to install Yeoman on my system using:

```
npm install -g yo
```

I have npm and node installed on my system.

I am getting this error:

```
getaddrinfo eai_again registry.npmjs.org:80
```

Here's is the the log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'yo' ]
2 info using npm@3.8.3
3 info using node@v5.10.0
4 silly loadCurrentTree Starting
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData yo
8 silly fetchNamedPackageData yo
9 silly mapToRegistry name yo
10 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
11 silly mapToRegistry registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
12 silly mapToRegistry data Result {
12 silly mapToRegistry   raw: 'yo',
12 silly mapToRegistry   scope: null,
12 silly mapToRegistry   name: 'yo',
12 silly mapToRegistry   rawSpec: '',
12 silly mapToRegistry   spec: 'latest',
12 silly mapToRegistry   type: 'tag' }
13 silly mapToRegistry uri http://registry.npmjs.org/yo
14 verbose request uri http://registry.npmjs.org/yo
15 verbose request no auth needed
16 info attempt registry request try #1 at 2:38:43 PM
17 verbose request id 09d26a48e3785699
18 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/yo
19 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
20 info attempt registry request try #2 at 2:38:53 PM
21 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/yo
22 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
23 info attempt registry request try #3 at 2:39:53 PM
24 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/yo
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:890:11)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:31:15)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:77:26)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for yo { [Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80]
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   hostname: 'registry.npmjs.org',
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   host: 'registry.npmjs.org',
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   port: 80 }
26 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
27 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
28 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Starting
29 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
30 silly install printInstalled
31 verbose stack Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
31 verbose stack     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:890:11)
31 verbose stack     at errnoException (dns.js:31:15)
31 verbose stack     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:77:26)
32 verbose cwd C:\windows\system32
33 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
34 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "yo"
35 error node v5.10.0
36 error npm  v3.8.3
37 error code EAI_AGAIN
38 error errno EAI_AGAIN
39 error syscall getaddrinfo
40 error getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
41 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
41 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
42 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Any suggestions?

I saw these links:

[Error installing yeoman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330273/error-installing-yeoman)
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11308