# npm sudo permisions for yeoman generator-webapp

Tags: yeoman

I have read this thread [npm / yeoman install generator-angular without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212175/npm-yo-keeps-asking-for-sudo-permission)
and resolve the permissions problem with the first way described here
https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814

```
echo 'export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
mkdir ~/local
mkdir ~/node-latest-install
cd ~/node-latest-install
curl http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz | tar xz --strip-components=1
./configure --prefix=~/local
make install # ok, fine, this step probably takes more than 30 seconds...
curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

So now it works for some generators but it doesn't work for the generator-webapp I still getting permissions error for that one probably because I have installed it before with sudo. 
How can I overcome this problem and maybe someone can describe on the answer what have I done with the above commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gist you link is incredibly old, it wants you to compile node with a custom prefix. After npm's inclusion in node I believe the last suggestion from that gist is the best option (and possibly only). It's also the one recommended in the [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212175/npm-yo-keeps-asking-for-sudo-permission) you link.

To summarize,

- Undo everything you have so far.
- Install node, preferably with a package manager instead of from source
- Set a local npm directory with `echo prefix = ${HOME}/.node >> ${HOME}/.npmrc`
- Add the bin folder under `prefix` to your path like you have done in `.bashrc`

Comment: what do you mean local dir ?

Comment: @pet I mean the bin directory in the specified `prefix`. In my example it would be `${HOME}/.node/bin`. In your post you used `~/local/bin`