# Bower Installation Errors

Tags: macos, node.js, npm, bower

Now I have installed Node and Npm and I run this command in terminal (yes I am on a mac):

```
npm install -g bower
```

Which follows with this output from the terminal:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Superfunnytogo
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.24
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower
npm ERR! fstream_type Directory
npm ERR! fstream_class DirWriter
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower'
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Superfunnytogo/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
Device-365-352:~ Superfunnytogo$ npm install -g bower
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Superfunnytogo
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.24
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower
npm ERR! fstream_type Directory
npm ERR! fstream_class DirWriter
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower'
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Superfunnytogo/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: What is wrong about this question?

Comment: Nothing wrong with this question. Not everybody can be expected to know about `sudo`. And in this case, using `sudo` isn't necessarily the right answer anyways. Here's a +1 to remove your negative vote tally.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You need root access or permissions to install  globally! Try :

```
 sudo npm install -g bower
```

Comment: Thank god I frigiin love this website, enjoy your first couple of reputation and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Using sudo, doesn't seem to be best of idea. Irsjng's answer seem to be better solution.

Comment: This is a sufficient answer  for system wide global installing of npm modules, if you would like the modules to be restricted to each user you could do as Irsjng suggested.

Comment: this doesn't work for me either. I get "sudo: npm: command not found"

Comment: My guess is that you have path reset on in /etc/sudoers but that is a separate issue

Answer (score 19):

Much better than using `sudo` is setting a user level prefix. For example in `~/.npmrc` set:

```
prefix = ${HOME}/npm-global
```

to use this folder for packages installed with `-g`.

Then you also need to set your `PATH` environment variable to include `${HOME}/npm-global/bin`.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for. Using sudo to fix this is like using a sledge hammer to drive in finishing nails!

Answer (score 4):

you shouldn't sudo bower right? I mean sudo npm install -g bower will work BUT here's the message I got:

Additional error details:
Since bower is a user command, there is no need to execute it with superuser permissions.
If you're having permission errors when using bower without sudo, please spend a few minutes learning more about how your system should work and make any necessary repairs.

http://www.joyent.com/blog/installing-node-and-npm
https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814

You can however run a command with sudo using --allow-root option

Answer (score 1):

---

If you've installed node/npm via Homebrew on OSX you may want to first run `brew doctor` and follow instructions before sudo-ing any system folders. In my case this brought up a nag about agreeing to an Xcode/iOS license:

`Builds will fail! Agree to the license by opening Xcode.app or running:
    xcodebuild -license`

After doing that and running a `brew update` I was able to install Bower globally as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I know that it's an old thread but I run into the issue recently after reinstalling Yosemite and xCode tools. In case anyone else gets stuck, what helped me was using the commands:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config
```

Following suggestion from the thread below:
https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/2262

Answer (score 0):

Using `sudo` with npm is discouraged.

Look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18277225/1857521 for a better solution to an almost identical problem.