# Trouble installing bower

Tags: npm, bower, bower-install

I'm a frontend developer trying to get into backend development and am currently working on my first webapp using node.js for the backend. I am having some trouble trying to install bower.

```
User@Users-MacBook-Pro-2 my-application (master) $ npm install -g bower
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules'
npm ERR! error rolling back  bower@1.3.5 { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 3,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules' }
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/User/workspace/my-application
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/User/workspace/my-application/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
User@Users-MacBook-Pro-2 my-application (master) $
```

I've tried using sudo (which of course is not the optimal solution), but that doesn't solve the problem for me. I've also searched around for other solutions ([Bower Installation Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21616785/bower-installation-errors)), but nothing has worked so far. Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

Thanks for your time!

--EDIT--
Using sudo I get the following:

```
User@Users-MacBook-Pro-2 my-application (master) $ sudo npm install -g bower
Password:
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-config
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/archy
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-endpoint-parser
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-logger
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-json
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-registry-client
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/chalk
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cardinal
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/chmodr
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/decompress-zip
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream-ignore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/handlebars
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inquirer
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/insight
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/is-root
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/junk
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lockfile
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mout
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/opn
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/osenv
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/p-throttler
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/promptly
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/retry
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/q
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request-progress
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/shell-quote
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/semver
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/stringify-object
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tar
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tmp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/update-notifier
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/which
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-config
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/archy
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-logger
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-endpoint-parser
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-json
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-registry-client
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cardinal
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/chalk
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/chmodr
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream-ignore
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/handlebars
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inquirer
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/insight
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/junk
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lockfile
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/decompress-zip
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mout
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/opn
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/osenv
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/p-throttler
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/promptly
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/retry
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/is-root
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/q
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/request-progress
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/shell-quote
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/semver
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/stringify-object
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tar
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tmp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/update-notifier
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/which
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/has-color
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-styles
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/configstore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.debounce
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/configstore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/object-assign
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/has-color
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/throttleit
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-styles
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/object-assign
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/mout/time.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/User/workspace/my-application
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/mout/time.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/mout/time.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/.bin'
npm ERR! error rolling back  bower@1.3.5 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/.bin']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/.bin' }
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: chalk@'^0.4.0'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.1.0","0.1.1","0.2.0","0.2.1","0.3.0","0.4.0"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:719:10)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:638:10
npm ERR!     at RegClient.get_ (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:105:14)
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:41:12)
npm ERR!     at fs.js:266:14
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:103:5
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/User/workspace/my-application
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! EEXIST, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/semver'
File exists: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/semver
Move it away, and try again. 

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/User/workspace/my-application
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/semver
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/semver/semver.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! errno 47
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:171:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/throttleit
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chown '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client/lib/lookup.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/User/workspace/my-application
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client/lib/lookup.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client/lib/lookup.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! fstream_finish_call chown
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:305:19
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:133:7
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! EEXIST, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/tmp/test'
File exists: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/tmp/test
Move it away, and try again. 

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/User/workspace/my-application
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/tmp/test
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/tmp/test/graceful.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! errno 47
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:171:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/decompress-zip/lib/extractors.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/User/workspace/my-application
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/decompress-zip/lib/extractors.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/decompress-zip/lib/extractors.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.debounce
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-json/test/test.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/User/workspace/my-application
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-json/test/test.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-json/test/test.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/lib/prompts/checkbox.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/User/workspace/my-application
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/lib/prompts/checkbox.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/lib/prompts/checkbox.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/retry/test/integration/test-retry-operation.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/User/workspace/my-application
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/retry/test/integration/test-retry-operation.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/retry/test/integration/test-retry-operation.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/read
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/User/workspace/my-application
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/configstore
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/configstore
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/request/request.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/User/workspace/my-application
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/request/request.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/request/request.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/User/workspace/my-application
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uuid
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/js-yaml
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.isfunction
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.isobject
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.now
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/handlebars/dist/handlebars.amd.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/User/workspace/my-application
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/handlebars/dist/handlebars.amd.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/handlebars/dist/handlebars.amd.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/read
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uuid
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.now
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.isobject
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mute-stream
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.isfunction
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/json-stringify-safe
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/forever-agent
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tunnel-agent
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/http-signature
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/oauth-sign
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-jar
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hawk
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/aws-sign
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-uuid
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/form-data
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash._isnative
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash._objecttypes
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mute-stream
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/json-stringify-safe
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/forever-agent
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tunnel-agent
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/http-signature
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/oauth-sign
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-jar
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/hawk
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/aws-sign
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-uuid
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/form-data
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash._isnative
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash._objecttypes
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/combined-stream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/asn1/0.1.11
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ctype/0.5.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/assert-plus/0.1.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/js-yaml
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cryptiles
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/boom
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sntp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/esprima
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/argparse
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/combined-stream
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ctype/0.5.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/assert-plus/0.1.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/asn1/0.1.11
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cryptiles
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/boom
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sntp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/argparse
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/esprima
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/0.0.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore.string
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/0.0.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore.string
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/User/workspace/my-application/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
User@Users-MacBook-Pro-2 my-application (master) $
```

--EDIT-- Updating Node 
When updating node, using the instructions here (http://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs). Now, however, npm does not seem to be working. Every time I use the npm command I get the following error thrown back at me:

```
User@Userss-MacBook-Pro-2 my-application (master) $ sudo npm install nodejs-inherits*

module.js:340
    throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'abbrev'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.15/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js:10:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
User@Users-MacBook-Pro-2 my-application (master) $
```

Comment: Is it the same error with ```sudo```? You are trying to install an executable globally in your system, like with any package, using sudo is quite acceptable here

Comment: Updated the post with what I get when I run sudo. Propblem seems to persist :/

Comment: It's a slightly different error though. Not an access problem anymore. I am concerned about this one: No compatible version found: chalk@'^0.4.0'.

Comment: Would you mind to update ```npm``` please?

Comment: Updated post with new error from updating node :) Thanks for your time

Comment: Didn't you install npm and node via Homebrew?

Comment: To be honest you seem pretty unlucky to me :) Hope we will find something !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seemed to be that my node version was old or corrupt. I managed to update node to a newer version (after first uninstalling it and getting rid of the abbrev-problem), and doing so solved all the problems described above. Can't really say I know exactly why, but something must have been quirky with my setup. Thanks for all the help Aurélien Thieriot!