# PhoneGap ios-sim installation without Root access

Tags: cordova, ios-simulator

I'm trying to install the **ios-sim** module without root access (for PhoneGap). 
I keep getting "missing ios-sim" even after installing it without the -g flag in the application folder. 
(I don't have root access to the machine)

Any way of making it work without root access ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes down to two options:

1. installing node.js somewhere your user can write to, or [set up your system to install global npm modules in your `$HOME`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18277225/878602)
2. install `ios-sim` locally somewhere and add that to your $PATH. For instance:
   `cd ~ && npm install ios-sim` then add `~/node_modules/.bin` to your `$PATH`

Comment: used the second option, worked like a charm! thanks.