# Installing npm modules globally without using sudo and updating the npmrc to install on the specified folder

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I wanted to install npm modules globally and it is not recommended to use `sudo` with it:
And this [question : npm / yeoman install generator-angular without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18212175/1328014) is the solution to it.

I followed this

```
echo prefix = ~/.node >> ~/.npmrc
```

And add this to my `.bashrc` file

```
export PATH=$HOME/.node/bin:$PATH
```

Now I have to install a global module, for example `express-generator`

```
npm install -g yo
```

But I am still getting an `EACCESS` error, and as read the log, it seems like npm is still installing global modules to the `/usr/lib/node_modules/` instead of `~/.node/`

```
Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/express-generator'
```

Comment: nvm might be an easier alternative, and installs to your home directory: https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just should start a new terminal session or run 'source ~/.bashrc'?

Answer (score 0):

You are not running it as sudo, run this instead

```
sudo npm install -g express
```