# Unable to install Grunt through Terminal

Tags: terminal, gruntjs

Operating System: Mac

So I was trying to install Grunt by typing the following into my terminal (through `/usr/local/bin`):

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

But I get this as a result:

```
Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:46:53',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli"
npm ERR! cwd /usr/local/bin
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
npm ERR! fstream_type Directory
npm ERR! fstream_class DirWriter
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli'
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:46:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /usr/local/bin/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

...and that doesn't look too happy! Can anyone help me out here?

Note: I also initially tried doing it from just my `usr`, without the `/local/bin` but that came up with errors too.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same result (OSX 10.9.5).  It likely doesn't matter where you're running the command from - I'd expect you'd see the exact same paths erroring out.

The problem appears to be that npm wants to put globally installed packages under `/usr/local/` (per https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html, executables in `/usr/local/bin` and modules in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` on *NIX systems, which here includes OSX).  This is not writable to your user on a Mac.

Your options are probably a few:

You could installing local to your project instead of globally  (omit the `-g`).  This would mean you need to reinstall the package in other project in which you want to use it.  This also means you'll need to set up your `PATH` when you access the project to point to any binaries (e.g., `grunt`) under the project (`export PATH=$PATH:./node_modules/bin`), which you could do with a script, but may still be annoying.

You can also likely run the install again with `sudo`, but there are some risks there (pointed out in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25259232/1795230).

Finally, you can change the 'prefix' (via `npm config set prefix ~/npm`), as presented here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21712034/1795230.  This has the downside of not being "global" for real (just global to all the projects of your user) as pointed out in comment [NPM won't install any package on Mac. New, clean build. `EACCES` & other errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25258361/npm-wont-install-any-package-on-mac-new-clean-build-eacces-other-errors#comment39379519_25259232), but that may work out fine, depending on your situation (works for me on my local dev machine).