# Spawn ENOENT running Gulp task and Cordova

Tags: gulp

I'm trying to automatize the process of prepare a machine to start developing with Cordova but i have many problems with CLI.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    jade = require('gulp-jade'),
    shell = require('gulp-shell'),
    coffee = require('gulp-coffee'),
    runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');

gulp.task('build', function () {
    gulp.src(['app/**/*.*'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('cordova/www/'));
});

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src(['app/styles/main.scss'])
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/styles/'));
});

gulp.task('cordova', function () {
    return gulp.src('/', {read: false})
        .pipe(shell([
            'npm install cordova'
        ]));
});

gulp.task('folder', function () {
    return gulp.src('/', {read: false})
        .pipe(shell([
            'mkdir -m 777 app'
        ]));
});

gulp.task('project', function () {
    return gulp.src('/')
        .pipe(shell([
            'cordova create . com.rvallespin.app app',
            //'cordova platform add ios',
            'cordova platform add android'
        ], {cwd: '/app'}));
});

gulp.task('plugins', function () {
    return gulp.src('/')
        .pipe(shell([
                'cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar & ' +
                'cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device & ' +
                'cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information & ' +
                'cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-battery-status &' +
                'cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device-motion &' +
                'cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device-orientation &' +
                'cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation &' +
                'cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera &' +
                'cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media &' +
                'cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture &' +
                'cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file &' +
                'cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer &' +
                'cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs &' +
                'cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-vibration &' +
                'cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts &' +
                'cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-globalization &' +
                'cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen &' +
                'cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser &' +
                'cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console'
        ], {cwd: '/app'}));
});

gulp.task('install', function () {
    runSequence('cordova', 'folder', 'project', 'plugins');
});

gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.watch("app/styles/main.scss", function (event) {
        gulp.run('sass');
    });
});
```

When i run "project" or "plugins" gulp always returns me an error with this message:

> Error in plugin 'gulp-shell' Message:
>       spawn ENOENT Details:
>       code: ENOENT
>       errno: ENOENT
>       syscall: spawn

What am i doing wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: I notice that you are making the project in a ROOT only folder: {cwd: '/app'}. Consider changing that to ./app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and I've been able to track it down. In my case the `node_modules` folder was owned by root, but since I wasn't logged in with root I didn't have sufficient rights to access the installed npm modules. So my fault was to install node modules using `sudo`.

**My solution:**
Shell commands:
`sudo rm -r node_modules/`
`npm install`

**If the problem still persists:**
If your npm installation complains about insufficient rights, you should fix the ownership of your `~/.npm` folder.
In my case I fixed it this way:

`sudo chown -R ~/.npm`

If that still wasn't enough this can help too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27955349/1646019

**EDIT:**
Another, maybe better solution might be this procedure: [npm / yeoman install generator-angular without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212175/npm-yeoman-install-generator-angular-without-sudo/18277225#18277225)