# How to update npm after set a local node prefix

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I've installed nodejs + npm on my Ubuntu machine using the following commands:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | bash -
apt-get install -y nodejs
```

And, in order [to use yeoman without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212175/npm-yeoman-install-generator-angular-without-sudo/18277225#18277225) I used the following commands:

```
echo prefix = ~/.node >> ~/.npmrc
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.node/bin"
```

After that, I can't update the NPM. If I run `npm update -g npm` the version number doesn't change, but, if I run the update command before the `echo prefix` command, the update works and npm is updated.

Comment: what is the output of the following command: `which npm`

Comment: @JevZelenkov the output is `/usr/bin/npm`

Comment: Could you run the following command and say where does the symlink point to  `ls -l /usr/bin/npm`?

Comment: @JevZelenkov I ran the commant and this is the output: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Jan 28 19:03 /usr/bin/npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js`

Comment: check out the updated answer and let me know if it works. If not, let me know what error messages are you getting. It also might be a good idea to close and open your terminal window again to get reset your $PATH environment variable back to normal

Comment: I've tried out all path changes, reset, close and reopen but not works (dont chage the version). But I saw a new thing. if i run `npm install -g npm` close and reopen the terminal the version number is updated! The output of the new install: `/home/nicolocodev/.node/bin/npm -> /home/nicolocodev/.node/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
npm@2.4.1 /home/nicolocodev/.node/lib/node_modules/npm`

Comment: yep, I've said that in my answer: "npm is written in nodejs and is managed via npm after the initial install." Just added an update command to make it clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### update

You have `node` + `npm` installed. By default `npm` uses `/usr/lib/node_modules/` directory to install global modules. Non-priveledged users normally don't have write access to that directory and as such, cannot install npm packages globally.

The command `echo prefix = ~/.node >> ~/.npmrc` tells `npm` to install global packages to `~/.node/node_modules` instead of `usr/lib/node_modules`.

After calling:

```
echo 'export PATH=$HOME/.node/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
```

all `npm` packages which provide binary scripts are added to $PATH (e.g. `yo`, `browserify`) but also `npm`.

`npm` package is managed via `npm` package manager itself. The following command updates `npm` to the latest version:

```
npm install -g npm
```

---

#### previous answer

NodeSource provides a binary build of `nodejs` + `npm`.

In [usage instructions](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#usage-instructions) they say to run both commands as admin for Debian systems:

```
sudo curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs nodejs-legacy
```

> The most important line in the setup script is this:
>
> ```
>  echo 'deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node ${DISTRO} main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
> ```

`node` + `npm` should be installed on your system globally now. Updates should be managed by `apt-get` from now on.

---

From what I can tell, you have another `node` + `npm` installed in your `~/.node` directory. I am not sure why you need it. As far as I know global `npm` packages are installed into `~/.npm` directory and they don't interfere with `npm` binary installed by `apt-get`.

In any way, if you really want to use your custom node installation from `~./node/bin`, you should export `$PATH` this way:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.node/bin:$PATH"
```

Also you can export `$PATH` automatically by adding this command to `~/.bashrc` file:

```
echo 'export PATH=$HOME/.node/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
```

*NIX looks for binary files (e.g. `npm`) in each directory specified in `$PATH`. It goes from left to right and executes the first matching binary file it finds. Somewhere in `$PATH` variable you have `/usr/bin`. If you want to `npm` / `node` from `~/.node/bin` to be found first, you should put that directory further to left in the `$PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Ok, that was my way: `echo 'export PATH=$HOME/.node/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc` then: `npm install -g npm`. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you want a well updated nodejs + npm :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo npm update -g npm
```

Et voilà!