# nodemon cannot run from shell (find module error 'got') OSX capitan 10.11.3

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, bash, nodemon

Running OSX el capitan 10.11.3

Recently returned to Node development (after about 3 months) only to find that Nodemon no longer runs on my system.  For example, executing the following command:

```
nodemon -v
```

Will return this error stack:

```
    module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'got'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/latest-version/node_modules/package-json/index.js:2:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
```

I have tried reinstalling nodemon and reinstalled node.js entirely.

```
npm uninstall -g nodemon
npm install -g nodemon
```

I don't see any dependency for 'got' in package.json at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon

```
{
  "name": "nodemon",
  "homepage": "http://nodemon.io",
  "author": {
    "name": "Remy Sharp",
    "url": "http://github.com/remy"
  },
  "bin": {
    "nodemon": "./bin/nodemon.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.8"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/remy/nodemon.git"
  },
  "description": "Simple monitor script for use during development of a node.js app.",
  "keywords": [
    "monitor",
    "development",
    "restart",
    "autoload",
    "reload",
    "terminal"
  ],
  "preferGlobal": "true",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "./lib/nodemon",
  "scripts": {
    "coverage": "istanbul cover _mocha -- --timeout 30000 --ui bdd --reporter list test/**/*.test.js",
    "lint": "jscs lib/**/*.js -v",
    ":spec": "mocha --timeout 30000 --ui bdd test/**/*.test.js",
    "test": "npm run lint && npm run spec",
    "spec": "for FILE in test/**/*.test.js; do echo $FILE; ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --timeout 30000 $FILE; if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then exit 1; fi; sleep 1; done",
    "web": "node web",
    "semantic-release": "semantic-release pre && npm publish && semantic-release post"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "async": "1.4.2",
    "coffee-script": "~1.7.1",
    "connect": "~2.19.1",
    "istanbul": "~0.2.10",
    "jscs": "2.1.1",
    "mocha": "2.3.3",
    "should": "~4.0.0",
    "semantic-release": "4.3.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chokidar": "^1.2.0",
    "debug": "^2.2.0",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "lodash.defaults": "^3.1.2",
    "minimatch": "^3.0.0",
    "ps-tree": "^1.0.1",
    "touch": "1.0.0",
    "undefsafe": "0.0.3",
    "update-notifier": "0.5.0"
  },
  "version": "1.8.1",
  "gitHead": "b292ae74b7c43407a52ce2d33d36ff218f4245ed",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues"
  },
  "_id": "nodemon@1.8.1",
  "_shasum": "75cfd7ac167e938cdab7313c839bc45a1859bb32",
  "_from": "nodemon@*",
  "_npmVersion": "2.14.9",
  "_nodeVersion": "4.2.1",
  "_npmUser": {
    "name": "remy",
    "email": "remy@leftlogic.com"
  },
  "dist": {
    "shasum": "75cfd7ac167e938cdab7313c839bc45a1859bb32",
    "tarball": "http://registry.npmjs.org/nodemon/-/nodemon-1.8.1.tgz"
  },
  "maintainers": [
    {
      "name": "remy",
      "email": "remy@remysharp.com"
    }
  ],
  "directories": {},
  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/nodemon/-/nodemon-1.8.1.tgz"
}
```

Also here is the nodemon.js file located at usr/local/bin

```
 #!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';
var cli = require('../lib/cli');
var nodemon = require('../lib/');
var options = cli.parse(process.argv);

nodemon(options);

var fs = require('fs');

// checks for available update and returns an instance
var defaults = require('lodash.defaults');
var pkg = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../package.json'));

require('update-notifier')({
  pkg: defaults(pkg, { version: '0.0.0' }),
}).notify();
```

I recently followed [this answer from user Passy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212175/npm-yeoman-install-generator-angular-without-sudo/18277225#18277225) to gain permissions over my globally installed packages with these two commands:

```
echo 'prefix = ~/.node' >> ~/.npmrc
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.node/bin"
```

And here are the top few lines of my .bash_profile

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:$PATH
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.node/bin"
```

Does it even make sense to have two lines there? Fairly novice coder here so I apologize in advance. Have searched pretty extensively for a solution on this one and I can't find anything that works so here goes! Will check in periodically to edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a hack that could help (npm3 may have missed a dependency):

```
cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon
npm install got
```

Comment: Fixed; thanks so much. Still unable to run nodemon without sudo though. I suppose I could try chown-ing that directory? Don't want to mess up anything haha